# How can I write only the file name instead of writing the entire path?

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I'm trying to use os.chdir so I can only write the name of the file within the directory(Table1.xlsx) instead of writing the entire path(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\Table1.xlsx"), but this code seems to not be working.

```
from win32com import client
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template")

excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = word.Documents.Open('Table1.docx')
book = excel.Workbooks.Open('Table1.xlsx')
sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
sheet.Range("A1:D5").Copy()    
wdRange = doc.Content
wdRange.Collapse(0)
wdRange.PasteExcelTable(False, True, False) 

os.remove('Table2.xlsx')

book.SaveAs('Table2.xlsx')
book.Close()
excel.Quit()
doc.SaveAs('TableOne.docx')
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

I get this error:
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Sorry, we couldn't find Table1.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: Did you make sure that file is actually in the directory you named? If you try `os.listdir('.')` after changing the directory, do you see the filename you are looking for? There is, as far as I can tell, nothing fundamentally wrong with how you've attempted to solve the problem, so this can only be a result of a problem on your end that can't be turned into a useful Stack Overflow question. This is not tech support.

Comment: Scratch that. It seems that the current working directory of the spawned process is not necessarily the same as Python's. A quick search found a similar question, but not a proper answer. I'll let this alone.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but is there a reason you need to be in the directory? I would use the pathlib library instead. 

`p = Path(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\filename.whatever")`. Then you can do `p.name` to get the file name whenever you need it. Or you can use the full path if you need to get it too. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Don't know if it would be compatible with the other libraries you are using, but it might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try To Make Variable with the path like:

```
path = "desired/path/to/project"
```

and then whenever you want to interact with saving or loading files:

```
book.SaveAs(f'{path}/filename')
```